# Skip transformation in $http response in case of error

Tags: angularjs

I have an `$http` service that make an API call and I have a `transformResponse` and error interceptor both attached to every call. In case of errors I can see that transform response gets called first, then followed by an interceptor. I do not want the transformation method to be called for error responses, I want it to skip right to the interceptor. How can I achieve that?

I know that I can put if `(response.status != 200)` into every transformation method, but I have a lot of these methods and I do not want to do that in each of them.

Comment: go with any custom providers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to go for Interceptors to play with request response in general.

```
myApp.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        // handle the case where the user is not authenticated
      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    }
  };
});

myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will also be useful

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.unshift(
        function (data, headers) {
            /* some code*/
            return data;
        });
}])
```